# jQuery AJAX POST does not work with Phonegap Build

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, post, build

I am having a problem doing a jQuery AJAX POST in an Android application using Phonegap Build. I have added:

1. Config.xml: set access origin *
2. All HTML files: set $.support.cors = true; $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
3. On remote server: set values for Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers

I have looked high and low for an answer to this. I have gone through several posts giving conflicting information, and I have tried a lot of the solutions mentioned, but none of them worked.

Here is what I am attempting to do:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://mydomain.com/mypage.aspx/myweb...",
  data: "{'sEnquiryText':'" + $("#textareaEnq")[0].value + "'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) { // Response function
    if (data.d == "Success")
      $("#lblInfoMsg").html("Enquiry sent successfully !");
    else
      $("#lblInfoMsg").html(data.d);
  }
});
```

This works fine as a web application when installed on a different domain (myseconddomain.com/mywebapp) as well as local IIS (localhost/mywebapp). But it does not work on an Android app made using Phonegap Build.

If someone could please look into this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is the error or the success callback ?

Comment: Try adding an error callback handler so you can see what the HTTP status code is or what the error message is. Can you determine if the request from Android makes it to your server?

Comment: I added 

`error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                   alert("errorstatus: " + xhr.status + " ajaxoptions: " + ajaxOptions + " throwError: " + thrownError);                }`

Comment: and I get a 500 Internal server error ("errorstatus: 500 ajaxoptions: error throwError: Internal Server Error"). This is the same error I get when accessing the file using file:// on my web browser. @AlexPereira

Comment: A 500 error indicates that the server had a problem processing the request. You should check to make sure that your service is properly working and that you are sending all the data needed for the service to process your request.

Comment: Ok. I got this working. 

It was a problem on our server side code throwing an error when trying to retrieve the URLReferrer from the Request object, which is NULL when calling from a file:/// URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need add to "res/xml/config.xml" some like

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->

<access origin="https://example.com" />

<access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" />

<access origin=".*"/>
```

Comment: Adding these to the *config.xml* in the phonegap root *www* directory is probably better than adding them to the platform configurations if you like to use, for example, `phonegap local build ios`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, I've concluded after many hours, is that XHReq POST is not supported inside an Android WebView, at least in the default setup by PhoneGap on the Android 4.03 device I'm using; tcpdump shows that the request does come out of the device, for the correct host and path, but as a GET, with no post data.  I checked the whitelist (phonegap default currently "*", so not an issue), made sure this was not a "POST caching" issue (by adding ?t= in the request url), and made sure I was making only asynchronous requests.  Same result;  POST comes out as a GET, and all post data is lost.

My solution has been to switch to using GET for this function, to avoid needing to send post data, via urls like "http://mydomain.com/endpoint?post-data=url-encoded-data-here&t=timestamp-here".   This was possible only as I had control over the server end of it as well, changing the endpoint to allow the formerly POST-only operation over GET if the data is inlined this way.

UPDATE:  I came back to this issue as I really wanted POST to work for other reasons (see post #21192670).

The *reason* why POSTs were failing was because of the MX configuration of my domain, and choice (or lack of) sub-domain in referencing it;  I used the root domain in the POST url, but the MX record had this directing to wwww.mydomain.com, which was then pointed to the correct ip address.  The POST was not getting through that redirect.

Comment: I am currently having this exact same problem but can't seem to solve it (would really rather not change AJAX requests to 'GET' requests).